# How to repeat register on assignment to another register?

Tags: vimscript, register

I'm trying to repeat register couple of times and assign it to another register whilst concatenating the strings.

For example:

```
let @d = '<td></td>'
let @r = '<tr>' . 10@d . '</tr>'
let @t = '<table>' . 10@r . '</table>'
```

However this syntax is not allowed.

Is there any different syntax or workaround to achieve that without repeating *n*-times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`repeat()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#repeat%28%29) function:

> `repeat({expr}, {count})`
>   Repeat `{expr}` `{count}` times and return the concatenated result.

Example usage:

```
:let @d = '<td></td>'
:let @r = '<tr>' . repeat(@d, 3) . '</tr>'
:let @t = '<table>' . repeat(@r, 2) . '</table>'

:echo @r
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

:echo @t
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```